# is it possible to use both x-api-key and bearer authorization token in api gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an api gateway (REST based) resource set up , with api key enable/required for my api. with api key set up , i include x-api-key in the header and it works. in the same service , can i enable/allow to clients to use Bearer token , as well (see example 2 below) . if so, how to configure my api gateway, to look for this token? or do i have to create a separate resource or a different api gateway all together?

header example 1

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
X-API-KEY:  abcdef12345
```

header example 2

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Authorization:  Bearer abcdef12345
```